# Error: "Selectors not implemented"

Tags: angularjs

I'm having difficulty selecting an element with angular. I must be making some silly mistake:

```
function Root($scope) {
    $scope.elem = angular.element('div');
}​
```

The error that results:

```
Error: selectors not implemented
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Object.JQLite [as element] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:1523:13)
    at new Root (http://fiddle.jshell.net/kzX9z/7/show/:28:27)
    at invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:2795:28)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:2805:23)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:4621:24)
    at $get.i (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:4200:17)
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:117:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:4185:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:3834:14) angular.js:5563
$get angular.js:5563
$get angular.js:4661
$get.Scope.$apply angular.js:7890
SNAKE_CASE_REGEXP angular.js:930
invoke angular.js:2788
bootstrap angular.js:928
angularInit angular.js:904
(anonymous function) angular.js:14397
trigger angular.js:1695
event.preventDefault angular.js:1930
forEach angular.js:110
eventHandler
```

[Reproduced in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzX9z/7/)

What am I doing wrong? I included jQuery. Isn't this supposed to work?

Comment: +10 same problem here, and this question helped :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's because jquery needs to be referenced *before* angular. JSFiddle registered Angular 1.0.2 FIRST and then the jquery verson you added as a resource.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This way Angular knows it can use JQuery and not JQLite. Once you do this, the selector will work in `angular.element()`

[Here's your fiddle, updated to reference the scripts in the right order (and altered slightly, see the comments)](http://jsfiddle.net/blesh/kzX9z/9/)

If you don't have JQuery, you can select the DOM Element manually.

```
var div = document.querySelector('div');
$scope.elem = angular.element(div);
```

Comment: Plus one for "if you don't have jquery", since ideally you would not have jquery if using angular.