# How to click a button and focus on another input in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, focus

I don't know how to focus on an input when clicking on a button in angularjs.

I create a simple demo which can't work here: http://plnkr.co/edit/NS0jJE9ttakNm8nc6QkZ?p=preview

This is the main code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $element) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.myfocus = function(){
    $element.find("#myinput").???? // what to do here?
  }
});
```

Comment: Please, do not try to access to DOM from your controller. Use directives for that.

Comment: What will the directive be?

Comment: I just answered essentially the same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518772/easy-dom-manipulation-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load jquery **before** loading angular.

See this updated plunker with load order changed and some changes to how you were trying to focus the element http://plnkr.co/edit/PLi1BiI83GKdAvSGufCP

and this previously asked question [Error: "Selectors not implemented"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480796/error-selectors-not-implemented)

And fastreload is right about not dealing with the DOM in the controller.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: "fastreload is right about not dealing with the DOM in the controller" -- so here is a [directive implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518772/easy-dom-manipulation-in-angularjs)

Comment: Mix jquery with angularjs is a bad practise. Try to use the element attribute in the link function of the directive to do this.This is not a right answer.