# custom directive doesn't display anything angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-factory

So I have a custom directive that makes an http get requests and displays on a another template. But it doesn't display anything

The **documentdisplay.js** file  where i have created the directive

```
/**
 * @author Karan Shah
 * 
 */

var documentDisplayModule = angular.module('ald.documentdisplay',[]);


documentDisplayModule.factory('documentDisplayAPI',function(){
    var fac ={};

    fac.getContents = function($http,docName){
        return $htp({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "/document/getContents/docName?="+docName
        });
    };
    return fac;

});


documentDisplayModule.directive('doccontent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $http,$routeParams, documentDisplayAPI) {

            documentDisplayAPI.getContents($http,$routeParams.doc).success(function(data,status){

                $scope.textofdocument = data;
            }).error(function(data,status){
                if (404==status){
                    alert("no text");
                } else {
                    alert("bad stuff!");
                }
            });            
        },
        templateUrl: "documentcontent.html"
    };
});
```

The **html page** where I am calling it

```
<!-- @author Karan Shah -->
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Document Display Contents</h1>
        <doccontent/>


    </div>
</body>
```

and the **templateUrl** the **documentcontent.html** which has the display

```
<body>
<div>
    Hello World
    <div>
        <a href="#/documents">Back to the List of Documents</a>
    </div>
    <br>    
    {{textofdocument}}
</div>
</body>
```

**error** that I am getting :

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/jqLite/nosel
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:78:12
    at JQLite (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:2365:13)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:6816:27
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:8074:11
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:11520:81)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:11520:81)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:11606:26
    at Scope.$RootScopeProvider.$get.Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:12632:28)
    at Scope.$RootScopeProvider.$get.Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:12444:31)
    at Scope.$RootScopeProvider.$get.Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js:12736:24)
```

The content is not displayed. I am not sure what is wrong here. Thanks

Comment: There is a typo in the factory: `return $htp`

Comment: I think that you shouldn't use $http inside a directive. Directives are made to manipulate the DOM. To retrive data from server, or send data to server you use $http inside a controller or a server.

Comment: well the spell correction didnt makae it run. I do have the $http inside the directive inside controller. I have another page which runs properly with the same situation. No idea why this one is not working.

Comment: Can you do a little more debugging and explanation?  Is your directive getting called (add some `console.log`s in your link and controller functions)?  In the network tab is a request happening?  What are you getting back?  As a side note you shouldn't have a body tag in your template...

Comment: In the network tab the status is OK. However my directive never got called.

Comment: ALso i am getting this error in the console which I dont know what it means Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: Solution :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480796/error-selectors-not-implemented

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory.  My guess is that `documentDisplayAPI` is using jquery selectors somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Controller inside directives must be used in this way

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, otherInjectables) { ... }
```

In your case `$element` is injected with name `$http`. When you are trying to invoke a rest call using `$http` it is actually trying to call the get method on `$element` and hence you are getting `Error: [jqLite:nosel]`
Try changing the controller to this

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, $http, $routeParams, documentDisplayAPI) { ... }
```

Also you need not pass $http to your factory instead you can directed inject in the factory

```
 documentDisplayModule.factory('documentDisplayAPI',function($http){
```